# How do I change a Django Template based on the User's Group?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Right now I have two different groups of users on my site: customers and businesses.

Right now I am only using one login that allows both user groups to see their profile page.

However, there are portions of the profile page I only want the Customer to see and portions I only want the business to see. How can I go about limiting what each group sees on this page?

Should I do it in the template with some sort of if statement? or is there some other solution anyone can let me know about?

Comment: Shouldn't you use [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#permissions) mechanisms instead ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is probably too old for you to care any more, but I stumbled here myself before figuring it out on my own.  For posterity, I found the following solution:

In your view, add something like this:

```
is_customer = request.user.groups.filter(name='Customers').exists()
```

In your template:

`{% if is_customer %} customer stuff here {% endif %}`

It relies on the fact that an `if` clause in a template will be evaluate to false for an empty list.

Comment: You can add `.exists()` to the end of that `filter()` call to get an actual boolean value for `is_customer`.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to avoid adding anything to your view functions, and you’re using the auth context processor (`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`) and `RequestContext` as per [@thyagx’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577513/how-do-i-change-a-django-template-based-on-the-users-group#answer-8826722), then you could use a template snippet like that suggested in [this Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/SeE8bJ5drM4/6bKTcfPLgPcJ):

```
{% for group in user.groups.all %}
    {% if group.name == 'customers' %}
        {% comment %}Customer-specific code goes here{% endcomment %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It’s a bit verbose, but it does mean you don’t have to do anything in your view (aside from using `RequestContext`), or write a custom context processor.

Answer (score 12):

What I did to solve this is:

1. I created a custom context processor which basically inserts new variables for you to use in your templates and added it to my settings. See more @ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext:

   ```
   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
       'django.core.context_processors.debug',
       'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
       'django.core.context_processors.media',
       'django.core.context_processors.static',
       'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
       'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
       'common.user_context.user_context'
   )
   ```
2. I went on to write the function `user_context` inside the file `user_context`, mine is like so:

   ```
   def user_context(request):
       if request.user.is_authenticated():
           is_admin = is_local_admin(request.user)
       else:
           is_admin = False

       return {
           'is_local_admin': is_admin
       }
   ```

   `is_local_admin` is just a function that checks if the user belongs to the Admins group or not.
3. Whenever I need this `is_local_admin` information in my template I use this to render it in my view, for example:

   ```
   return render_to_response('create_user.html', {
       'form': form
   }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
   ```

The important part is the `RequestContext`, which loads the custom context processor we build in step 1.

Now in your template you can just use:

```
{% if is_local_admin %}
    <h1>You can see this</h1>
{% else %}
    <h1>Nothing here</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps someone. In summary: **take a look at custom context processors, they are worth the read.**

Answer (score 7):

I implemented this through a template tag, based on what I found [here](http://www.abidibo.net/blog/2014/05/22/check-if-user-belongs-group-django-templates/).
Perhaps it can be useful to someone.

In utils/utils_extras.py:

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

register = template.Library()
@register.filter(name='has_group')
def has_group(user, group_name):
    try:
        group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
    except:
        return False  # group doesn't exist, so for sure the user isn't part of the group

    # for superuser or staff, always return True
    if user.is_superuser or user.is_staff:
        return True

    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()
```

Then in the template itself:

```
{% load utils_extras %}
{% if user|has_group:"mygroup" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if  'group_name' in user.groups.get.name %} do smth {% endif %}
```