# Django Auth: How to assign permission to each record in table?

Tags: django, authentication

I have a table called system_object which have main menu data. I wanna assign permission to each menu, so, for example user A can see the menu, but user B can't see it. How can I do that with Django Auth?

Should I define a permission for each record in system_object model?

Answer (score 0):

Create Group and either use decorator to check whether user has permission to view data or not or in your view, add something like this:

```
is_customer = request.user.groups.filter(name='Customers')
```

In your template:

```
{% if is_customer %} customer stuff here {% endif %}
```

It relies on the fact that an if clause in a template will be evaluate to false for an empty list. (source :- [How do I change a Django Template based on the User's Group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577513/how-do-i-change-a-django-template-based-on-the-users-group))

Comment: Menu A has a row in system_object, Menu B has a row too and so on ... I wanna User x can see menu A but can't see menu B. Something like per row permission ...

Comment: you can implement something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577513/how-do-i-change-a-django-template-based-on-the-users-group other method might be something like http://www.abidibo.net/blog/2014/05/22/check-if-user-belongs-group-django-templates/

Comment: I think i miss understood Django auth system! I don't want to define permission for a model! Some permissions are independent from models! I dun know where can i define these kind of permissions!

Comment: @MehranMeidani you don't have to define permission. just create group and assign user on different group based on their permission, later implement logic at view as shown in answer above

Comment: So, each group have some permissions. right? how can I define these permissions independent from models? I call it modelless! I have more than 90 menu items, so, I need more than 90 permissions ...