# Django: Return to template along with template variables

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

I am using Django to build a student-teacher portal.
I have two groups of users - teachers and students. If user is a teacher, i need to provide a different template (a form for selecting student's registration number). I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577513/how-do-i-change-a-django-template-based-on-the-users-group) link to do the same.

Here are the code snippets:

**home.html**

```
    {% if is_teacher %}
    <p style="color:blue; text-align:center; font-size:160%"><b>Course taken: <span style="color:green"><a href="course/">IT000</a></span></b></p>
    <form action="/" method="post" align="center">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div align="center">{{ form }}</div>
        <input type="submit" value="Get student's results!" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:10px"/>
    </form>
    {% else %}
    <p style="color:blue; text-align:center; font-size:160%"><b>Performance for the subject <span style="color:green"><a href="course/">IT000</a></span> is shown below.</b></p>
    {% endif %}
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def home(request):
    is_teacher = request.user.groups.filter(name='teachers').exists()
    if is_teacher:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = Regno(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
               selected_reg = Student.objects.filter(regno=request.POST.get('regno'))
               return render(request, 'home.html',{'selected_reg': selected_reg,'form':form})
        else:
           form = Regno()
           return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form,'user':request.user,'is_teacher':is_teacher})
    else:
        selected_reg = Student.objects.filter(regno=request.user)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'user':request.user,'is_teacher':is_teacher,'selected_reg':selected_reg})
```

Here, Regno is a Form for the teacher to enter student's registration no.

When a teacher initially logs in, he is displayed the form. However, after he submits the form, it is not displaying the form. It executes the {% else %} part of the template. How do I make sure the is_teacher template variable is passed on to this template after the teacher submits the form?
I read about Django sessions but I'm not sure if it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the is_teacher every time, you should use `RequestContext` to pass it along with your requests.

Looks like in your post call on form submit, you are not passing is_teacher variable. (in below code)

```
if form.is_valid():
    selected_reg = Student.objects.filter(regno=request.POST.get('regno'))
    return render(request, 'home.html',{'selected_reg': selected_reg,'form':form})
```

You should add `is_teacher` in above.

Also, better way to handle it via [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/) -

```
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='has_group')
def has_group(user, group_name):
    group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
    return True if group in user.groups.all() else False
```

and in the template -

```
{% if request.user|has_group:'teachers' %}
    ....
{% else %}
    ....
{% endif %}
```

You can avoid passing it with each call. Hope it helps.